# jQuery in ASP.NET User Control

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I would like to use jQuery in ASP.NET User Control. Can some one tell me how to do it in a right way. I am trying to implement datepicker on a text box. I am new to ASP.NET and jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Employer.ascx.cs"  Inherits="Employer" %>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/Styles/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       $("#SDate").datepicker();
       $("#EDate").datepicker();
    });
</script>
<p>
    Company:<asp:TextBox ID="CBox" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ERVal" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter The Company Name" ControlToValidate="CBox"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</p>
<p>
Start Date:<asp:TextBox ID="SDate" runat="server" CssClass="DatepickerInput" />
</p>
<p>
End Date:<asp:TextBox ID="EDate" runat="server" CssClass="DatepickerInput" />
</p>
<p>
Pay:<asp:TextBox ID="PayBox" runat="server" />
</p>
<p>
Role:<asp:DropDownList ID="RLBox" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="Admin" Value="Admin" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Employer" Value="Employer" />
</asp:DropDownList>
</p>
```

Comment: show us some code what you tried and what problems are you facing

Comment: This is the code I Tried

Comment: @SatishNissankala - No wonder it's not working....there's no code.

Comment: @Steve Wellens-just added the code in the question.

Comment: do you have ANY jQuery working on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your rendered html you'll see that the IDs have changed. This is a part of webforms.

Try:

```
$("#<%= SDate.ClientID %>").datepicker();
```

Comment: also have a check that the container page for your user control has no javascript/jquery errors in it see in mozilla firebug error console

Answer (score 1):

replace you script block with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".DatepickerInput").datepicker();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$(function(){});` is the same thing.

Comment: i replaced the jquery selector @Jack to get rid of generated client ids in web user control markup.

Comment: Oh I totally missed that, sorry.

Comment: it's ok jack it does happen sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[id$=SDate]").datepicker();
$("input[id$=EDate]").datepicker();
```

I got it to work on my box.  The dollar sign is a type of wild card attribute selector...any IDs that end with the text.

Comment: @satish if this worked for you then consider marking it as selected answer just click the right sign to accept it as your answer it will help other OPs like us :)